# How to get the up time of a kafka topic in command line

Tags: shell, apache-kafka

My question is how to get the up time of a `kafka` topic 
I tried with this command

```
./kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2182/zk/kafka/prod --topic flume-generic
```

but it didn't show the informations I need, 
I searched in the `kafka` docs but I didn't found what I need. Maybe someone can help me

Comment: I found by myself, Zookeeper manage kafka topics and is able to give this informations by doing `./zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2182/zk/kafka/prod ` then `get /brokers/topics/TOPICNAME`

Comment: Topics have no such concept of "up time"

Comment: Not the topic in kafka itself but the node who host the topic in zookeeper

Comment: The leader or all of the replicas?